# Namespaced Custom Events Trigger

Tags: jquery

I'm stumped on how namespaced custom events are supposed to work in jQuery. I got the impression from [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) that triggering a namespaced custom event will only fire handlers specifically bound to that event. Instead, it seems the namespace is pretty much ignored. Example below and live code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kZCBw/1/

```
    $(document)
        .bind("reset.one", function(){ console.log("reset.one event detected");})
        .bind("reset.two", function(){ console.log("reset.two event detected");})
        .bind("cheese", function(){ console.log("cheese event detected");});

        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            console.log("firing reset.one event");
            $(this).trigger("reset.one");
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function(){
            console.log("firing reset.two event");
            $(this).trigger("reset.two");
        });
        $("#btn3").click(function(){
            console.log("firing reset event");
            $(this).trigger("reset");
        });

        //btn1 click should only trigger handlers bound to "reset.one"
        //and yet it triggers anything starting w/ "reset"
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!
-matt

Comment: Side note: works nicely with  jQuery 2.1.4 and jQuery 3.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can at least corroborate your example an add an observation.

If you make the button the listener (see http://jsfiddle.net/kZCBw/2/), better reflecting the sample code in the documentation, it works as expected.

But if you move it anywhere higher up in the DOM tree (see http://jsfiddle.net/kZCBw/3/), it fails.

At first, I suspected that this was because the namespace wasn't being bubbled up with the event object, but I appended the following code (live example at http://jsfiddle.net/kZCBw/4/):

```
$('*').bind('reset', function(e){
    console.log(e.type + '.' + e.namespace + ' detected at ' + e.currentTarget);
});
```

As you can see, the namespace is being bubbled up just fine.

While the behaviour you're looking for (namespace remaining effective at higher level DOM nodes) is not explicitly exemplified in the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events), I feel that it should be the way namespaced events work. To this extent, you can now begin the "bug or feature" hunt.

A makeshift way to accomplish what you're looking for without touching the jQuery source code is to just filter the event using the EventObject (I suspect this is how namespaced events are accomplished in jQuery in the first place) inside the event handler.

Comment: +1 For a v good answer. Note that the appropriate property to test is `e.namespace`.

Comment: Thanks to lonesomeday for the kind words and helpful advice. A note to the OP: you can get a guide on how to use the EventObject in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). Alternately, just putting in `console.log(e)`, where `e` has been assigned to the EventObject instance will give you a very quick overview of the object and help you develop an intuition on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks Steven and lonesomeday. after some more digging, it turns out this is a known-issue. See: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6913 so, yes, it seems the only option today is to test for the namespace / classname

Comment: For posterity, this is now fixed in jQuery 1.6 - see here http://jsfiddle.net/kZCBw/7/

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll happily chalk this up as one of the extremely few times in which something I thought was a bug was actually a bug.

Comment: Namespacing appears to still be broken in jQuery 1.7.2, at least when triggering events like: $.event.trigger('update.global.options'); It will fire all elements which are attached to 'update', as far as I can tell.